# Cannot run ds-timer with Wine

Tags: 12.04, installation, wine

I am trying to get [this program](http://niondir.de/blog/archives/286) to run in Wine, it goes through the installation process, but then fails to start up.

I don't have the technical know-how myself to find a workaround, it might be something simple?

Comment: we need more information, why it can't start? is it giving any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The program itself seems to be made in .NET. So it won't open using Wine.

You may be able to open it using Mono (install the Windows version of Mono with Wine).

Comment: sorry.. no errors, simply doesnt start up.. click on the icon, run in wine, nothing, no error code for me to search

Comment: Sorry, it cut some of my answer, fixed it now.

Comment: "Sorry, it cut some of my answer, fixed it now. – VegBerg 23 hours ago
 .NET programs that "need Windows" (for example, by calling native Windows API functions) and thus cannot run on Mono in Ubuntu may be able to run in Wine on Ubuntu if you install the Windows version of Mono with Wine (since Wine can run the Windows version of Mono)"                                            Thanks, that worked perfect :)